# Notification area tool to manage Apache and MySQL on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, windows-services

Can you suggest a modern and supported alternative to "MySQL System Tray Monitor" and "Monitor Apache Servers" tools? The first one (bundled with *MySQL GUI Tools*) was discontinued long ago and the second one is not present in most third-party binary builds (something to take into account now that official Apache binaries no longer work with official PHP binaries). I'd like it for me and my clients.

I basically expect a notification area icon that:

- Shows whether the services are running or not.
- Allows to start, stop or restart them quickly.
- Plays well with User Account Control.

I thought there might exist a generic tool out there to handle Windows services but I couldn't find the appropriate keywords...

Comment: Voting to Close/Migrate ('off topic'/'belongs on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/)').

Comment: I've got a nice answer for my development tools (Apache and MySQL). I'll try SuperUser to see if I can find something more generic (not only for programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAMP and XAMPP are two of the most famous AMP(Apache MySQL and PHP) solutions, you can install them and use their respective packages... or you can install the Apache, MySQL and PHP individually and just use WAMP or XAMPP as a "monitor" (it is not their main task but you can use them like that if you want, this is just a work around).

Comment: Witty... I've extracted `xampp-control.exe` (124KB) into my hard disk and it works nicely.